# MD5 Hash of a table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm not finding anything in the manual or SO that quite matches my need.

Scenario - moving DB2 data to another DBMS - high volume both in terms of number tables and amount of data.  It is critical that data lands on the far side *exactly* as it is at the source.

I'd like to add some controls to ensure the data at the target represents the data from the source accurately.  While we are doing the usual `count(*), max(field), min(field)` and that has helped in identifying data conversion issues I'd really like have an overall quick check that would prompt further investigation if something is off.  We have been doing full automated compares but that is pretty time consuming.  My initial thought is an MD5 hash of core business fields on each table - similar to what is done on files...  and `hash(<field>,0)` looks like it might be suitable - in short tests I'm getting the same result on the target side for individual records. I'm not seeing a function that would let me do an MD5 of a complete column or table though.

I expect others have already encountered this need so perhaps could provide some pointers that would get me going the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the __version__ (`db2level` output) of your Db2-LUW server?

Comment: @mao v11.1.4.5 fixpack 5.

Comment: As you observe, there's not a built-in for whole-table hash, or whole-row, but if you export to file, that is possible at file level with suitable scripting.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work for my use case - too large volume to export at once so exporting deltas over time.

Comment: faced the some need a couple of month ago, there is no simple way to do this. it is a nightmare if the two RDBMS dont use the some coding (cf ISO 8859-P15 to UTF8). the best way is to use replication